# Airbag warning light for Lexus IS 250

Tags: warning-light, supplemental-restraint-system

My airbag warning light has been on.  I took it to the dealer, and he says I need a new wiring harness.  It will cost freakin' $3500.  This Lexus dealer has generally treated me well, and their reps don't act like they are on commission, but that sounds like a lot.  He says it is a functional issue, meaning that the airbag could malfunction if I don't get this fixed.  Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the airbag on the Lexus IS 250 commonly has your problem.  Other people have been quoted about a $3000 price but that was a couple years ago.

Sometimes, depending on the year and miles of the car, people have been able to get Lexus to cover some of the cost even if they were just past warranty because it is a known safety issue.  The customer service number I saw was: 1-800-25-LEXUS.

Some one with a similar issue on [my.is website.](http://my.is/forums/f127/airbag-light-stays-lit-dashboard-431549/index2.html#post6512555)

> 82141-53F10 WIRE, INSTRUMENT PAN - $1183.82
>   REPLACED SHORTED SRS WIRING HARNESS PER TSIB LSB016708 - $821.81
>   All in all after misc stuff and tax, $2058.20. Could have been much worse. Calling Lexus customer satisfaction 1-800-25-LEXUS was way worth it.

Also see:

- [clublexus.com](http://www.clublexus.com/forums/6002601-post1.html) (it's a 350 though)
- [motor.com](http://www.motor.com/newsletters/20120213/WebFiles/SS4_Lexus.html) (more specific info)

The price you were quoted seems about par though, unfortunately.

---

*EDIT*

From what I read, if the airbag light is on the airbag system is shut off and will not deploy.  It's best if you get it fixed before driving much. ([my.is](http://my.is/forums/f127/airbag-light-stays-lit-dashboard-431549/#post6502968))

Comment: Do you have any links or references?

Comment: I'll have to dig up where I read that.  I should have done so in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Lexus, in 2006, 2007, installed a wiring harness that was too short.  The harness plugs become loose and in some cases the wire insulation becomes chafed and shorts out the airbag system.
In an instant your car value decreases, your airbags won't work and if you're in a State that requires inspections, your car will not pass.  Lexus was aware, early of the problem and will now fix it for you for $2.5k-$3k.
You paid for lotsa airbags in a car whose airbags will not function properly.!
What to do?  Take a few minutes and file a complaint with NHSTA.

Comment: This is cause for a recall, since this affects the public safety, but first you need to sort out which wire is shorting and show that this is a manufacturer defect.